# How to force neat linewrapping in Print?

Tags: front-end, formatting

I am regularly annoyed by the fact, that a neatly arranged `Print` statement gets ruined by a large piece of data, which - instead of linewrapping "in place" - is pushed below the preceding label. See example:

```
Print[
  "test line 1...............: ", {1, 2, 3}, "\n",
  "test line 2...............: ", 
  Pane[Table["testestestestestestestestest", {10}], 800], "\n",
  "test line 3...............: ", {1, 2, 3}
  ];
```

which produces the following output:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Question**

Is it possible to tell the `Pane` object to wrap its content in a way that does not force the *Table* to shift to the next line, but is linewrapped in-place (i.e. right next to "*test line 2*")? Of course I can specify an explicit width for `Pane`, but since I don't know how big is my screen (user's screen), how large in pixels is the label text ("*test line 2*"), and many other factors, it just seems useless to give a magic number that should cover all situations. `Full` and `All` does not work either. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The option [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageSize.html) with the value `Scaled` should give better results, and it will adapt to the size of the notebook window. You will still need to define the value of `Scaled` to allow for likely widths of the label in the first column.

```
Print["test line 1...............: ", {1, 2, 3}, "\n", 
  "test line 2...............: ", 
  Pane[Table["testestestestestestestestest", {10}], 
   ImageSize -> Scaled[0.5]], "\n", 
  "test line 3...............: ", {1, 2, 3}];
```

[image]

I agree that `Grid` is a better option here. But if you stick with `Print`, for example because you want to keep this output as a side effect of evaluation, you might also want to consider wrapping that long table output in `TableForm`.

Comment: Exactly what I  was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just realized, that the simplest method would be to use `Grid` instead of `Print`. Still it would be nice to solve this by using `Print` and `Pane`.

```
Grid[{
  {"test line 1...............: ", {1, 2, 3}},
  {"test line 2...............: ", 
   Pane[Table["testestestestestestestestest", {10}], 800]},
  {"test line 3...............: ", {1, 2, 3}}
  }, Alignment -> {Left, Center}, Spacings -> {.5, 1}]
```

output:

[image: Mathematica graphics]